# How to group by with substring in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table called `filestatistics`:

```
id    file    userid    datetime
 1    p1          99    2017-04-15 09:05:10
 2    exp1        99    2017-04-15 09:25:17
 3    p2          99    2017-04-15 09:45:46
 4    exp2        99    2017-04-15 09:55:07
```

and I want to group and get the total entries per user them according to their filename but excluding the 'ex' string.

My query is:

```
SELECT file FROM filestatistics WHERE userid = 99 GROUP BY file;
```

My query above results in 4 entries which is wrong.

What would be the correct query to group the files per user?

Desired output is

```
2 files for userid = 99 
//since p1 and exp1 are grouped as 1
//since p2 and exp2 are grouped as 1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're after. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The ex string should be removed only if it's at the beginning? What if you your file = 'exp1ex'?

Comment: if p1 and exp1 are same why are you saving them as different values then why dont you save them as p1 instead?

Comment: p1 and exp1 are two parts of the same topic (elearning thing) but they needed to be counted as one in the report I am making.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to get the files:

```
SELECT userid, REPLACE(file, 'ex', '') AS file, COUNT(id) AS cnt_files
FROM filestatistics 
GROUP BY REPLACE(file, 'ex', ''), userid
```

To get the `COUNT` of files of each user you can use the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT REPLACE(file, 'ex', '')) AS cnt_files
FROM filestatistics 
GROUP BY userid
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6046f8c142d246fb60c1c32dd829221e)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested it, but hope this one will help you :-

```
SELECT substring_index(file, 'ex', -1) as file_count, count(*)
FROM filestatistics
GROUP BY file_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select replace(file,'ex','') as file,count(userid),userid from filestatistics GROUP BY  userid, replace(file,'ex','')
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more general (eg. case `file` `= 'exp1ex'`)

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN substr(file,1,2)='ex' THEN substr(file,3,LENGTH(file)) ELSE file END AS file 
           , COUNT(*) AS RC
    FROM filestatistics 
    WHERE userid = 99 
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN substr(file,1,2)='ex' THEN substr(file,3,LENGTH(file)) ELSE file END;
```

Answer (score -1):

The substr query can be written in mysql. Consider this link as reference.

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php

The query should be like

```
SELECT file FROM filestatistics WHERE userid = 99 AND file!=substr("ex",0,2) GROUP BY file;
```

Comment: Have you checked the result?